# Plotting Lat/Long on map - D3.js v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I have a simple map of the United States and I'm trying to plot some test Lat Long points. I found [this block](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/7745589) explaining the process but I'm having trouble converting the syntax to v4. Even when I run the exact code in the block it throws the same errors.

I can see the `d3.geoMercator()` kind of 'flattens' the map. Is this needed? It seems trivial but I like the natural curvature the US map has without this.

Curious what the correct approach is, and if some of the code is even necessary. Particularly this part:

```
  projection //Added from block -- What is this doing?
    .scale(1000) //Added from block
    .center([-106, 37.5]) //Added from block
```

My code with the broken additions, I added comments to the code added: https://jsfiddle.net/fettww66/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that bl.ock you linked, you only need **two** changes to make it running with D3 v4:

> - `var projection = d3.geo.mercator()` ↦ `var projection = d3.geoMercator()`
> - `var path = d3.geo.path()` ↦ `var path = d3.geoPath()`

Here is the updated bl.ocks using D3 v4: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/d0b530924ef2aae3436840a1dbb3a39f

Regarding your fiddle, the issue is very simple: you are using an **already projected** JSON. Just set the projection to `null`:

```
.projection(null)
```

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vypu9qwr/

Comment: Thanks, @Gerardo. The code runs fine, however, the Lat/Long listed in the code variable `aa` has the point being placed in San Francisco. When I run the code it is placing it in western Utah. I have found that I can manipulate the `projection.scale(1000).center([-106, 37.5])` and it will move the point. I'm guessing I need to edit this to some correct value. I just don't know what it is. Here's the current fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/Lv5knc0n/](https://jsfiddle.net/Lv5knc0n/)

Comment: Well, I answered **two** questions of your post (what changes are needed for using D3 v4 and why the fiddle was not working). It seems that you have even more questions than that! Sorry, it's too much, I have a policy of not answering a post that has several questions.

Comment: You can always make a *new* question, though. That way, you keep 1 problem per post (actually, people can cast a close vote as *too broad* for questions in which OP asks several issues).

Comment: No problem; I created a new post. Thanks for the help thus far and for the best practices tip.