# Plotted lat/long points on map are being placed incorrectly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a set of lat/long `37.786453, -122.490402` that when mapped correctly maps to San Francisco. However, in my code. It is mapping to western Utah. I am able to manipulate the location of the point by altering this section of code that has been unchanged from the original block I utilized:

```
projection
  .scale(1000)
  .center([-106, 37.5])
```

What correct value(s) need to be placed here? If I remove the section entirely it places the point in eastern Oregon.

Here is the current fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lv5knc0n/

This is a follow-up question regarding plotting lat/long on a map using d3.js. Link to the first post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43905688/plotting-lat-long-on-map-d3-js-v4/43905750#43905750).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fiddle is showing features with two different projections:

- A null projection for the US topojson
- A Mercator projection for the point

For the topojson shown with a null projection:

The US topojson referenced has come up in many other posts, it is a composite Albers projection of the US (which incorporates multiple projections in one frame). The data in it is already projected, hence the use of a null projection. The null projection simply takes the x,y coordinate of each point and translates it to svg coordinates with no transform (in mapshaper.org or any geographic software, it will appear upside down as svg coordinates start at the top, while geographic coordinates start at the equator, below your map).

Ultimately you are matching an Albers to a Mercator - and when you make changes to the Mercator projection:

```
projection
  .scale(1000)
  .center([-106, 37.5])
```

You are not changing the topojson since the path generator for it doesn't use a projection. You are only changing the point's projection. And as you are using two different projections, the same geographic point will be represented differently in each projection - making alignment of multiple points problematic if not impossible (depending on the points and projections).

---

There is a relatively straightforward solution, use unprojected data for your US Counties (where the spatial data consists of lat long pairs) and project it with the same projection as your points. This will allow you to use one projection for both points and paths, or any other features, allowing you to scale and zoom all features at once (otherwise, you will need to use a geoTransform to manipulate the counties data while trying to match those changes with changes to the projection, not an ideal solution).

Try using the json in this [block](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3734308) ([here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json)).

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew. I don't know if I ever would've figured that one out.